# Child Process Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have main APP and child JS. I want to run child JS in child Process 
this child.js is an schedule loop to check every hour on db.

How to do it?

I will post the Quick Code

**Child.js**

```
exports.main = () => {
  console.log('Running API DAEMON')
  updateInventoryInit();
}
function updateInventoryInit(){ //something happen };
```

**Main_APP.js**

```
var api_DAEMON = require('./api_daemon');
api_DAEMON.main();
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just use `cron` to run the script every hour?

Answer (score 0):

As far what I can understand, you can try this following code:

**main.js**

```
 const cp = require('child_process');

 let child = cp.fork(__dirname + "/child.js");

 child.on('message', (msg) => {
     console.log("from child : ", msg);
 }); 

 setInterval( () => { 
      // sent msg to child in every hour  
      child.send( 'check-db' );

 }, 'every-hour');
```

**child.js**

```
// receive msg
process.on("message", (data) => {

   // perform your task

   // after complete task
   process.send("complete");

});
```